# how to get desired column using foreign key from another table in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, model

So there are two tables:

```
products (model name: Product)
categories (model name: Category)
```

The `products` table contains column name as `prd_cat_id` which is a `foreign key` with reference to `cat_id` in the categories table. Every `product` belongs to a single `category`.

I want to establish a relationship between them so that whenever I want to get data from the `products` table the name of the `category` can be also fetched.

Models for products and categories table:

```php
class Product extends Model {
    use HasFactory;
}

class Category extends Model {
    use HasFactory;
}
```

There are 4 columns in the `categories` table `(cat_id, cat_name, cat_desc, cat_image)` but I just want to use `cat_name` with the `product` table's data.

How can I fetch the data accordingly? I would like to output the result in a blade template.

Answer (score 0):

To join another table which not using `id`. You need to specify key.

If you have one-to-one relation then you can use this `hasOne` relationship

In `Product` Model to get category data,

```
return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Category', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```

For More, [Laravel One to One Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)

Comment: other table using id, cat_id

Comment: You need to match `prd_cat_id` & `cat_id` in order to get data. Right? So specify these keys in above relationship respectively. Sometimes it is confusing so verify keys by interchanging values given in relationship.